# Laravel eloquent get details from related table

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, eloquent

I don't understand how to return info back to `blade` `template` if I have two related tables:

First table is standard `Laravel` 'users' table
Second table:

```
Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('code', 10);
    $table->string('description');
    $table->float('size');
    $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned();
    $table->string('status')->default('pending');
    $table->boolean('deleted');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('created_by')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
}
```

Than I have two `Controllers`: `User` and `Recipe`
`Recipe` have

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
}
```

and `User` have

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Recipe::class);
}
```

actual output looks like this (`RecipesController`):

```
$recipes = Recipe::latest()->paginate($perPage);
return view('admin.recipes.index', compact('recipes'));
```

everything looks OK but column `created_by` contain `users` primary key witch is integer. How can I display users name? This is something like inner join but is it possible to do that in eloquent? Or I completely misunderstanding those public functions in a `Model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user relationship in your Recipe model is missing the foreignKey:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'created_by');
}
```

You can then eager load the users with your recipes in the controller:

```
$recipes = Recipe::with('user')->latest()->paginate($perPage);
return view('admin.recipes.index', compact('recipes'));
```

And finally you can access the user in the view:

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
    {{ $recipe->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

You can read more about the inverse of the one-to-many relationship in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Comment: I have error: Class 'App\User' not found. I don't understand in witch Model